# Unresolved dependencies and gradle build error

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle, android-studio-3.4

I'm opening a new empty activity in my present project and it is showing the unresolved dependencies error and at the same time showing the Gradle warnings. I'm using Android Studio 3.4 and my Gradle version is 3.4.1.It is also showing add Google Maven repository and sync project, I tried that already but it wont help at all. How can i fix this issue?

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
               [url "https://maven.google.com"][1]
            }
        }
    }
```

I added this already but it wont help at all.

**First Activity**

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Numbers Activity**

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
    }
}
```

I expect to run the NumbersActivity just fine but the case is not so.

Comment: Add your dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `build.gradle` maven portion like this: `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`

or 
just use `google()` instead of this elaborated lines

Comment: thanks it helped alot. Moreover i got a new error now & this time its a runtime error, can you help me with that?

Comment: Sure, just let me know what is it. :)

Comment: thanks for you help anyways. I solved it already on my own, you know debugger came in handy this time for me, bdw it was a Run Time error.

Comment: If you got any help from my answer give the answer an up vote and select it as the answer you were looking for. I will motivate me to help others. Thanks

Comment: hey can you help me an error? Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867930/could-not-find-method-implemetation-for-arguments-com-android-supportappcomp